# Devise session[:previous url] empty after logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have used [this how-to](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update) to redirect back to current page after sign in, sign out using Devise.
It is almost always working but one case is not.

I also have redirected to login page after logout. Without this redirection everything is working.

The case that is not working is: when I **logout and login again**. In the login page I print session[:previous url] and it is empty and after login, it redirects to the root path·

This behavior seems pretty strange to me... Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

This is the redirection that I mentioned. This way, session[:previous url] is empty in the login page

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    login_path
end
```

This is how it is working **without** the redirection. This way, session[:previous url] is working properly

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    session[:previous_url] || root_path
end
```

Comment: Have you included `store_location` in your application controller and the `after_filter`?

Comment: I saw somewhere that I should use before_filter :store_location
 if I use before_filter :authenticate_user!
I was using after_filter before and the behavior was the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the Devise's method `after_sign_out_path_for` to achieve this. In your application controller add this method

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  request.referrer
end
```

Comment: it seems that you didn't undertand my problem. I tested now and your code has the same behavior as without the redirection.

Comment: I updated the question with my code. I hope that it is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a very old question but many people (including me) still have this problem.

Devise resets the session during logout so as RSB wrote, you need to use `request.referrer` to redirect user back to where they came from.

In your specific case you may want to change the method to following

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  session[:previous_url] = request.referrer
  redirect_to login_path
end
```

However expecting the app to remember where user was when they log out and log back in is... quite exotic.